# why sharepoint2010 wiki not consider as popular wiki?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

I am working on SharePoint 2010 wiki , before that I have no experience with WIKI I have checked wikimatrix.com also for differences but they don't have have SharePoint 2010 in their list.Although the comparison is available was 2007 Posted.
I need technical reasons why SharePoint 2010 WIKI is not considered as Standard WIKI ( any technical limitation) which others WIKI solutions are providing like ( TikiWiki,DokuWiki,Confuluence etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason i personally don't like the Sharepoint Wiki is formatting. More often than not you are unable to format parts of your text because the editor just doesn't work. Starting with a fresh text is easy, everything works and formatting is no issue. But texts that have been changed and reformatted several times seem to be so messed up in their markup that the editor doesn't recognize its own work. So you end up copying the source mess into a text editor, clean it and paste it back into sharepoint.

Another problem in my opinion is the simple fact that you *have* real formatting at all. That's almost as bad as declaring Comic Sans as the default font in the first place. If your editors don't adhere to a standard formatting scheme some sites of your wiki may soon look like a 1990s web site, including the big yellow headline and blinking text.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer I will definitely consider it.but still need some more technical reason to my Tech.Manager :(

Comment: there aren't that many purely technical reasons. There are some limitations - you need IIS, you need Windows Server, you need a sharepoint site that eats memory like the cookie monster. Speed is generally bad compared to almost all pure wiki solutions out there. The biggest issue for me is user acceptance, both from the editor and the reader point of view. A wiki without someone who likes to use it is just a waste of resources.

Comment: Agreed & Thanks for your prompt Feedback